# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline Woes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jwplayer, asset-pipeline

I am using JW Player to play streaming audio files. I have built a custom skin but can't get the player to show up. When you build your custom skin, you zip up the skin along with the skin.xml file (where the flash reads for its image files and other settings) and then you point the javascript config object to point to that skin zip file.

```
jw = {
                    'flashplayer':'/assets/player.swf',
                    'controlbar': 'top',
                    'autostart': 'false',
                    'width':'400',
                    'height':'49',
                    'playlist': '[]',
                    'skin':'/assets/skin.zip',
                    'dock':'false',
                    'wmode':'transparent'
                }
                jwplayer('player').setup(jw);
```

For some reason the player does not show up on staging or prod envrionments, however, I can download the zip file from the browser. Would the new Rails 3.1 asset pipeline have anything to do with this?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out! I am using coffeescript to go along with my Rails 3.1 instance and if you add `.erb` to the end of your coffeescript files, the system will run the file through ruby first... so above instead of `flashplayer:/assets/player.swf`, it is now `'flashplayer':"<%=asset_path('player.swf')%>"`